# Axis covers the labels in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Recently I encounter a problem in ggplot2: The y.axis covers the labels which I use the red circle to mark on the picture. I don't know how to change the margin or space between the label and y.axis. Could you answer me how to do that. I will appreciate for you.  Thanks .

[image]

```
p1 <- A %>% ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Family,value), y = value, fill = factor(name))) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1,  stat="identity")+
  coord_polar() + mytheme + # + scale_fill_manual(values = my_pa)
  ylab("") + xlab("") +  #theme(legend.position = "bottomright")+
  theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle=0,hjust = 2) ) +
  theme(  axis.line.x =    element_blank()  ) + mytheme
```

Here is my data:

```
A <- structure(list(Family = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 17L, 17L, 17L), .Label = c("Apiaceae", "Asteraceae", 
"Betulaceae", "Brassicaceae", "Cannabaceae", "Celastraceae", 
"Chenopodiaceae", "Convolvulaceae", "Crassulaceae", "Fabaceae", 
"Fagaceae", "Hydrangeaceae", "Juglandaceae", "Lamiaceae", "Malvaceae", 
"Moraceae", "other", "Papaveraceae", "Phyllanthaceae", "Pinaceae", 
"Pittosporaceae", "Poaceae", "Polygonaceae", "Ranunculaceae", 
"Rhamnaceae", "Rosaceae", "Rubiaceae", "Salicaceae", "Sapindaceae", 
"Simaroubaceae", "Solanaceae"), class = "factor"), name = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Apr", 
"Jun", "May"), class = "factor"), value = c(22.82, 26.03428571, 
10.64043478, 26.24230769, 4.226938776, 0.425217391, 0.918461538, 
3.372857143, 1.82173913, 12.57, 4.876530612, 5.963478261, 0.143846154, 
3.210204082, 0.976521739, 0.240769231, 2.474489796, 1.41, 4.983076923, 
3.707142857, 4.703478261, 2.016923077, 1.159183673, 2.72, 1.356923077, 
3.231836735, 9.620434783, 0.001538462, 1.918979592, 0.146521739, 
0.753076923, 1.794693878, 9.949130435, 0.734615385, 0.222040816, 
0.116086957, 0.306923077, 0.779591837, 0.411304348, 0.339230769, 
4.182653061, 2.712173913, 0.295384615, 11.41285714, 16.84652174, 
1.925384615, 4.143877551, 7.702173913, 1.856923077, 12.20408163, 
1.701304348, 0.094615385, 3.310612245, 0.69, 0.319230769, 0.252653061, 
0.124347826, 0, 0.146122449, 13.39652174, 3.761538462, 0.142857143, 
0.06826087, 3.196153846, 0.717346939, 4.979130435, 0.09, 0.921836735, 
0.229565217, 0, 0.927959184, 0, 0.04, 0.812857143, 0, 0.604615385, 
0.003061224, 0, 7.26, 0.005102041, 0.04826087, 0, 2.425918367, 
1.693913043, 0.433076923, 0.053265306, 0.253913043, 5.235384615, 
0, 0.036956522, 1.46, 1.328163265, 0.612608696)), row.names = c(NA, 
-93L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Just a small note that `mytheme` variable is not included in the example. Could you either remove it or provide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround would be to switch off clipping `coord_polar(clip = 'off')`. Other option that might help, is using different angles for the axis labels. Here's a combined solution (not perfect, but you should get the idea):

```
angles <- c(seq(90, -90, length.out = nlevels(A$Family)/2),
      seq(90, -90, length.out = nlevels(A$Family)/2))


A %>% ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Family,value), y = value, fill = factor(name))) + 
    geom_bar(width = 1,  stat="identity") +
    coord_polar(clip = 'off') +
    ylab("") + xlab("") +
    theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = angles, hjust = 0.5),
          axis.line.x =  element_blank())
```